# Running into an error when I try to import firebase into my node project

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

So, tried to import firebase into my web app. I started directly by going through the documentation and replicated the same into my project. Initialized it as such:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
const firebaseConfig = {
    //Config Stuff
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Running into the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

This is how the file is defined in HTML, at the very bottom inside :

```
<script
      defer
      type="module"
      src="/webpages/codingspace/codinglogic.js"
></script>
```

I tried to fix it by going through the firebase documentation but that didn't help.

Comment: It's typically a good idea to do a web search using the error message to see other people who ran into the same problem. This one comes up a lot.